# Autostart apps on different screens in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, boot, automation

Is there a way to autostart apps and have them appear on a specific screen?

I have a startupscript that looks like this:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
progList = Array("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE",_
     "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe",_
     "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS4\Dreamweaver.exe",_
     "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe",_
     "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE")
For Each prog in progList
    'WScript.Echo "File Name: " & prog
    shell.run """" & prog & """", 1, false
    WScript.sleep 20000 '20 seconds
Next
```

But I have 3 screens. Is there a way to have appX appear on screen 1, appY to appear on screen 2 and appZ to appear on screen 3 etc in the startup process?

Comment: I'd have thought the applications in question would 'remember' which monitor and screen location it last had affinity to and open back up there. For example, Outlook always runs on monitor 2 in my setup, and always reopens there. Of your list, I use all but Dreamweaver and they all open to the monitor/location they were last located.

Comment: Yes but if I want to have 3 instances of Firefox and each on a separate screen?

Comment: @chris_45: if each firefox instance is actually a separate process (meaning they're using separate profiles), then they should obey the open-on-last-used-screen rule.  if you actually mean 3 firefox windows (all part of the same firefox process, running the same profile) then you need something different.

Comment: Ok how do you start different instances with Firefox?

Comment: `firefox.exe -P other-profile -no-remote` will startup a second firefox instance using `other-profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but on my multiscreen setup i use this program

[Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)